# How to link css file in vb asp.net project

Tags: html, css, asp.net

How to link css file in vb asp.net project

Right now my css file is not beeing run from Home.aspx files. What is my All_Body.css file path that I should type in Home.aspx file.

I need to put this code on server so I can not use full path with my computer username

project Files:

```
>MyWebsite
    >Styles
        >All_Body.css
    >UI
        >Home.aspx
>Master.master
```

**All_Body.css full path**

```
C:\Users\Dave\source\WebSites\MyWebsite\Styles\All_Body.css
```

**Home.aspx**

```
<asp:Content id="Home_Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~\Styles\All_Body.css" />
...
</asp:Content>
```

**Master.master**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head> 
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Home.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    ....
</asp:Content>
```

**Master.master**

The link to your CSS file should be in the <head> element of the master page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/All_Body.css" />
</head> 
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I updated the path to your CSS file which was incorrect; this link is relative to the root. Also, the `"~/"` only works when you include `runat="server"` - either way it is not needed when using a relative link for CSS.  You also had a malformed head content placeholder. The content placeholder for the main content was missing from your master page. There was no form tag so nothing could work. In fact the code you presented would not even compile. If you simply used the standard Web Forms template out of the box with the master page option, it would have worked.

Tip: The easiest way to get the CSS link correct in a master page is to drag the CSS file from Solution Explorer into the <head> section of the master page in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, just made all the changes, still no luck

Comment: Everything was mangled, like you made too many changes by hand. I suggest creating a new (simple) project with just a master page, home page and CSS file in the Styles folder and use that to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared my browser cache and it worked.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't reload the css or js files, so as a developer you have to do **hard refresh /reload** every time you update the css or js files and you must add query string like **?v=0.01** after the href or src when you publish the website to the server and change the number every time.

ex:

*href="styles.css**?v=0.01**"* 
*src="main.js**?v=0.01**"*

Now the browser will think this is a new file and will reload it in the client browsers.

Comment: In development, all one has to do is empty cache and/or do a total CTRL-F5 browser refresh. It is totally unnecessary to do what you suggest in production since we shouldn't be testing in a live environment in the first place. In addition, this should be a comment since it does not directly address the original problem.

Comment: Mr @IrishChieftain  I'm considering the case when you do updates to the website and your website's been already used by some clients, so to force their browsers to reload the new updated .css and .js files you've to add a query string or change the files names.@ ikhlas-ahmed had solved the issue but it might occur when making updates to the production so I wan't to make it clear .

Comment: Most developer/designers would configure their browser tools to automatically empty the cache on reload. Besides, all they have to do is hit CTRL-F5. This does not address the original problem as #ikhlas' original code, as presented, would not even compile.